# kernel mode caching for MVC in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, outputcache

I know we can enable kernel mode caching for asp.net applications using ".aspx". But how can we do with MVC application?. MVC application doesn't have any extensions for files.

Answer (score 0):

try put in your webconfig the following line:

```
<system.webServer>
    <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false" />
</system.webServer>
```